# java function returning clarification

Tags: java

I have a question:

I have this code

```
public Player returnPlayerCurrentTeam(String playerName) {
    for (Player p : currentTeam) {
        if (p.getName() == playerName) {
            return p; // position A
        }
    } 
    return null; //position B: why do I have put "return null" or "return p" here? (i.e. return p or return null)
}
```

I am not sure why I need to put a "return null" statement or a "return p" statement in position B. If I assume the currentTeam must have a player that matches the name given by playerName, does it mean my for loop will exit once a match is found and it will exit from position A? if so, why is it that I need to have another return statement in the position B?

I am asked to put it because the IDE says "missing return statement", so by guessing, I know I have to put a return statement there.

Another question is "null" an object of a subclass of Player? since I specify my return type to be Player. And putting "return null" there seems to solve the problem as putting "return p" there in position B, so does it mean "null" is a subclass of Player? (as far as I understand, any subclass of Player can be returned, is it true?)

thank you

Comment: You need to return at the end of the function in case the return statement inside the loop is never executed. Also, no, `null` is not an object at all; and you should not use `==` to compare strings in Java.

Comment: You can assume that, but the compiler can't.

Comment: @kaya3 hello, so we should only use == to compare primitive type such as Integer, float, double. But string is not a primitive type, so we use .equals() , is it correct? because .equals() actually compare the address in memory, is it correct?  Also is it possible to know the difference between Int and Integer? are they mutually substitutable?

Comment: You can use `==` to compare reference types in some specific cases (e.g. comparing with `null`, enum types, or when object identity is actually what you want to check), but using `==` on strings (other than `== null`) is basically never correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the name might not be found. You could save the first found player to a local variable (and perhaps end the loop). That eliminates the variance. Also, use `Object.equals(Object)` for comparing reference types (not `==`). Like,

```
public Player returnPlayerCurrentTeam(String playerName) {
    Player foundPlayer = null;
    for (Player p : currentTeam) {
        if (p.getName().equals(playerName)) {
            foundPlayer = p;
            break;
        }
    } 
    return foundPlayer;
}
```

Finally, `null` is actually a special type in Java that means no value.

Comment: I am just wondering so null can be used as a "return" object for any function? say if it is public Integer , public float, public Animal..... so if return type is an Integer, or a float, or an animal, I can just replace with null, is it true? Also could you confirm if it is true that any subClass of Player can be put in the return statement? like if P2 is a subclass of Player, then I can put "return P2" instead in my return statement, is it correct?

Comment: Any reference type. You can't use `null` with a `float`. Yes, if `P2` is a subclass of `Player` then `P2` is also a `Player`. And can be used anywhere a `Player` can. You should try reading the Java specification. It really answers these questions in great detail. Specifically, I refer you to [Chapter 4.1. The Kinds of Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1).